# Applying sort -u to one specific column in a CSV file?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a very large (several GB) input file in this format:

[image]

What I want to do is to dedupe the CSV file based off of its first column. The aim is to keep the highest value copy of the value within column 1. The file is already sorted with that in mind, now I just need to clear the dupes.

I tried applying `sort -u`to the column but that obviously applies to the whole line instead of just the column. I have also tried `sort -t, --parallel=8 -uk1,1 -k2rn test.csv` but that did not work either.  Is it possible to achieve this with `sort` or will I need to use some other tool to achieve this job?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Please post text as text. Please post sample input file. Is the file really delimetered by a comma, the image looks like a tab separated file? Please show example output you want the command to output.

Comment: Your file shown is not a CSV file, it appears to be a file with space separated values which means the first field will actually be multiple fields. Unless, the delimiter is a `tab` character. Please post example *text* from your file instead of pictures of text.

Answer (score 3):

> The aim is to keep the highest value copy of the value within column 1.

I assume you mean the highest value in column 2 for each unique column 1 string?

One way using the often useful [`GNU datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -t, -g1 max 2 < input.csv
```

For each group of the same first column value (`-g1`), print the maximum of the second column (`max 2`). Does require the input to be sorted on the first column, but it sounds like that's already the case. The ordering of the second column doesn't matter for this approach.

Or since it looks like the file is sorted on both columns (ascending first, descending second numerically), using `awk` (As pointed out, this will be more portable if that matters):

```
awk -F, '!($1 in seen) { seen[$1] = 1; print }' input.csv
```

This prints only the rows with the first occurrence of each unique value in the first column, which will be the highest number for that string. It works by storing the first column values in a hash table, and skipping lines where it is already present.

A third option that might be worthwhile if you'll be doing other, more complicated work with the raw data is loading it into a sqlite or other database and using SQL to do the heavy lifting. Not worth the bother for a one-off thing, though.

Comment: `awk` is probably the most likely utility installed by default, but the `datamash` solution is interesting. Unclear whether CSV actually means *comma-separated-values* in this case. The OP can adjust the delimiter as needed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OP did use comma as a field separator in the `sort` attempts in his question. Agree that a picture of tabular text instead of actual textual data is a pain and adds ambiguity.

Comment: Correct you are -- that's why I hate pictures of text instead of the actual data. You got the UV regardless, can't give 2 `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) starting from this TSV

```
04 ford f 150 recalls   0.34
04 ford f 150 recalls   0.27
04 ford f 150 recalls   0.14
2004 ford f 150 recalls 0.32
2004 ford f 150 recalls 0.2
```

and running

```
mlr --tsv -N top -f 2 -g 1 -a ./input >./output
```

you will have

```
04 ford f 150 recalls   0.34
2004 ford f 150 recalls 0.32
```